# Tomato vs X-Wrt Wireless Router Firmware - which is better?

Tags: wireless-router

A few years ago, I've switched over from DD-WRT to Tomato and I haven't looked back since. Before I did, I poked around with OpenWRT but found it too confusing or annoying to use (and I'm a CS major and setup and configured Linux servers using SSH).

I'm probably not going back to DD-WRT because of all the controversy but I was wondering how X-Wrt is nowadays? From the screenshots, it looks a lot more featured packed than Tomato and that definitely has its appeal. Then again, simplicity has its advantages to.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Super User is not a discussion board and isn't a place for general feedback and thoughts.

Comment: X-WRT is a web interface for OpenWRT.  i've been using it for years and it's very capable, but for most of my tweaking i go straight to the SSH interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been very happy with Tomato over the last couple years, and honestly, how much more do you need in a router?